# TypeError : not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, printing, typeerror

```
print("The mangy, scrawny stray dog %s gobbled down" +
"the grain-free, organic dog food." %'hurriedly')
```

The above statement gives me the error "TypeError : not all arguments converted during string formatting".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `+` between your string literals. `+` has lower precedence than `%`, and adjacent string literals are concatenated anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` has lower precedence than `%`, so with your code, Python tries to evaluate `"the grain-free, organic dog food." %'hurriedly'`, which does not make sense, because that format string does not contain the `%s` part.

Remove the `+` between your string literals:

```
print("The mangy, scrawny stray dog %s gobbled down "
      "the grain-free, organic dog food." %'hurriedly')
```

Adjacent string literals are concatenated anyway, so you do not need the `+`.

Alternatively, if you're using Python 3.6 or higher, use an f-string:

```
adverb = 'hurriedly'
print(f"The mangy, scrawny stray dog {adverb} gobbled down "
      "the grain-free, organic dog food.")
```